# How publish / (hosting in server) asp solution with sharpdevelop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-hosting, sharpdevelop

I'm trying to publish a asp solution with sharpdevelop but I don't find the publish function in sharpdevelop.

How publish or hosting in server a asp mvc 4 Razor solution with sharpdevelop 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a new WiX setup project first.

[Creating an Installer with SharpDevelop](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2007/01/08/CreatingAnInstallerWithSharpDevelop.aspx)